Why is ubuntu shows me read/write error. I've installed it in external SSD
After working sometime on ubuntu 22.04 LTS it freezes and shows this on screen.


Your filesystem is read-only, probably a result of a filesystem error, so the filesystem needs to be checked.  Either put the SSD on another system or boot an install media to run fsck on it. Also, from the smartmontools package, run smartctl -a on the SSD to see if there are any disk problems. Are you using a vm or encryption?
